# Given T:R^n -> R^n , T(vn)=v1 and for $ n-1\ge i \ge 1$ $T(v_i)=v_{i+1}$ T is diagonalizable ? if yes ,than show [T]E Diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Given $$B=\left \{v_1,v_2,...,v_n  \right \}$$ a Base in $R^n$

Given$$ T:R^n -> R^n$$ , T(vn)=v1 and for $ n-1\ge i \ge 1$ $T(v_i)=v_{i+1}$ T is diagonalizable ? if yes ,than show [T]E where E is the standard Basis for $R^n$

i feel i dont get to the buttom of the answer

my try was :
when$ n=k , k>3$ than : $p_A(t) = t^n+1 $
and so the eigen values is : i,-i,i...,i

than
$D=diag(i,-i,i,-i,...,i)$
T is diagonalizable over $C $ \

when
for n=3
$$t=1, \frac{-1\pm\sqrt{3}i}{2}$$

then

$D2=diag(1,z,\bar{z},1,z,\bar{z},...,1) $

am i correct ? can some one give a full proof on this question ?

General i assume will be :
$$\det(A-tI)=(-1)^n\left(t^n\displaystyle-1^{n}\right)n>1,$$

Edit:
when $n>2$
[image]

Comment: Can some one give me the correct proof , i do understand what the possible proof and the way and the whole idea of it.

Answer (score 2):

Put $v_{n+1}=v_1$. Let $\zeta$ be any of $n$ complex roots of $1$ and $v=\sum_{k=1}^n \zeta^{-k} v_k$. Then
$$Tv=\sum_{k=1}^n \zeta^{-k} v_{k+1}=\zeta\sum_{k=1}^n \zeta^{-k-1}v_{k+1}=\zeta v.$$

So $\zeta$ is an eigenvalue of $T$. Since $T$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, its matrix is diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: but where is [T]E and what happens if n=2 ,n=3 and above that ,this is not detailed this is just the idea of the solution

Comment: @cisco_guy I don’t know what is $[T]E$ and have no need to consider it to answer the question. For each $n$, in particular for $n=2$, $n=3$, and above that, $T$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues, which are complex roots of $1$. Therefore $T$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: no , the question ask for showing [T]E
this is the matrix acording to standard basis
i will edit my question to show
Also, the question is formal question so ,there is a need to prove , not just to conclude

Answer (score 1):

Assume $B=\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$ basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then, following $T(v_{k})$ for each $1\leq k \leq n$, we then get:

$[T]_{B}=\begin{pmatrix} 
0 &0&0&...& 1\\1&0&0&...&0\\.&&&&.\\.&&&&.\\.&&&&.\\0&0&...&1&0
\end{pmatrix}$

Now if you prove $[T]_{B}$ is diagnolizable then you prove T is. Can you take it from here?

Comment: This also holds if $B$ is not the standard basis.

Comment: Yes just fixed it

Comment: i understood this idea , but it is vary between n=2k and n=2k+1

and also im not sure my proof is full

t^2+1 over C is : (t+i)(t-i) 
and if n=3\\


$t^3-1 = (t-1)(t-z)(t-\bar{z} )$

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand you. What varies between $n=2k, n=2k+1$?

Comment: for the proof to be full we need to consider the parity of n, Beacuse if n=2 than we have : 
-i,i in the diagonal and if n=3
than $1,z,\bar{z}$